# How to retrieve the search related data from the database to a listitem?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, search

My previous work was retrieving search data from the database to a grid view.

But now how it is possible to retrieve like this.

[image]

Should i use a `listbox` or `dropdownlist` in asp.net

Comment: You may look at jquery autocomplete.

Comment: Exactly its a good option. Thanks Raphael. I will work on it and give the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using textbox and autocomplete, please see full example from the following reference:

http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/AutoComplete_From_Database.aspx

Comment: Adel Thanks for the link, I will go through it.

Comment: Hi in the link u had given, they add a reference called `System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService`. But I dont find the this `scriptservice` reference when i tried to add it to the project

Comment: basically, the method which you have to add should be as a web service, so once you add new webservice this will be automatically known..

Comment: So I should add a webservice as a service reference right?

Comment: right click, add new web service, and add the autocomplete function inside as of the example..

Comment: I did the same the error shows in the `AutoCompleteExtender` as it is not compatible with `textbox`

Comment: That's another matter, this should be something related to the AjaxToolkit, try to have the same version of your framework, example 3.5, then should be the AjaxToolkit is 3.5 also..

Comment: I am using both as 4.5

Comment: Hi Adel in that example they were using autocomplete for strings, What if I want to use only integers?, Is it possible to list it out as array of integers?

Comment: same concept, add validation part on change only, use it as string and parse the value after posting it, just to make sure that they added a number

Answer (score 1):

you can try this -

```
    <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <script>

  $(function() {

    var availableTags = [

      "ActionScript",

      "AppleScript",

      "Asp",

      "BASIC",

      "C",

      "C++",

      "Clojure",

      "COBOL",

      "ColdFusion",

      "Erlang",

      "Fortran",

      "Groovy",

      "Haskell",

      "Java",

      "JavaScript",

      "Lisp",

      "Perl",

      "PHP",

      "Python",

      "Ruby",

      "Scala",

      "Scheme"

    ];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({

      source: availableTags

    });

  });

  </script>

</head>

<body>



<div class="ui-widget">

  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>

  <input id="tags">

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

To get the data from database we will need to build a handler that will process all the requests of AutoComplete and return the results back to the ASP.Net Web page.

```
    <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Search_CS" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;

public class Search_CS : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select ContactName from Customers where " +
                "ContactName like @SearchText + '%'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        sb.Append(sdr["ContactName"])
                            .Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                context.Response.Write(sb.ToString()); 
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Harish This looks pretty easy. I will try and let u know

Comment: What if i want to retrieve data from database

Comment: Dhinesh,I've edited the answer for getting the data from database.

Comment: I have written a script for retrieving from the web handler         `<script type="text/javascript">       
        $(function () {
            $(".search").autocomplete("UsernameSearch.cs", {
                width: 200,
                formatItem: function (data, i, n, value) {
                    return value.split(",")[0];
                },
                formatResult: function (data, value) {
                    return value.split(",")[0];
                }
            });
        });
</script>`

Comment: Harish I am not good in jquery but AJAX appears easy to me when it comes with database